# Which is the leading facebook module for Drupal 7 a complete site integration?

Tags: social-network

There are 3 main FB integration modules for Drupal 7;

- [FB](http://drupal.org/project/fb)
- [FBconnect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect)
- [FBoauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth)

There are tons of discussion threads around the net and drupal.org describing the pros and cons of each module. From all these threads, this is what I've gathered. If all you want is FB login capabilities for your users. Then FBoauth is your best bet. FBconnect does a few of the 'other' features pretty well but requires some bug fixes to be stable. FB is great if you want APP integration for your site. But my question is;

If you wanted your site to do;

- User Registration
- Content Posting to Wall Stream
- Comment Stream
- Friend Inviting

Which is the best module to be able to have those features built into your drupal site?

Comment: fboauth is for login/registration only (but it does it amazingly well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [FB](http://drupal.org/project/fb). It offers all what you need.

I've been in the same dilemma and went with that one.

I suggest to try all of them and see for yourself though. Don't waste time with modules which offer third party integration - they rely on registration on those websites and usually paying a fee to them. I think it's silly registering and paying for a third party service in order to use another (free) third party service.

Comment: The third part services can often keep up with changes quicker that the modules (and therefore site maintainers can).  I have had two instances in the last few months where a client's site broke because of FB changes that required FB module changes and/or FB SDK updates.

Comment: It is true that FB often changes/updates and that it causes problems with module, but my experience was completely the opposite - often those third party services were slow to act and you are locked up as you do not have access to the code. Not all FB changes affect everything, so certain update does not have to be priority for them. At least in Drupal case you can hack and update the module yourself if it is critical.